# Having problems with saving a list of strings to postgresql database

Tags: python, string, postgresql, list, psycopg2

I've been struggling with this problem for like an hour, and I still don't know how to resolve it. The problem is that I have to store into a database a list of strings, but I don't know how to do it without triggering an error because it says syntax error, can you help me?? Here's the code.

```
def filter_info(self):
    patrimonio1 = {"conto_corrente": self.conto_corrente.active,
                   "azioni": self.azioni.active,
                   "obbligazioni": self.obbligazioni.active,
                   "autovetture": self.autovetture.active,
                   "polizze": self.polizze.active,
                   "terreni": self.terreni.active}
    patrimonio = [k for k, v in patrimonio1.items() if v]
    return patrimonio

def save_info(self):
    with ps.connect(dbname=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS, host=DB_HOST) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            patrimonio = self.filter_info()

            with open('account_email.txt', 'r') as f:
                email = f.readline()
                cur.execute(f'''SELECT patrimonio from "'{email}'" WHERE "email" = '{email}' ''')
                cur.execute(f"""UPDATE "'{email}'"
                                SET patrimonio = '''{patrimonio}'''
                                WHERE "email" = '{email}';""")
```

Comment: Share the error

Comment: Are you sure that your table name is similar to an email address?

Comment: Your biggest issue is using `f` strings to build the query. Beside the lack of type adaptation it is a big SQL injection risk. See here [Query parameters](https://gist.github.com/drocco007/6e44ac1a581546c16e67) on how to do this properly and here [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) for the Python --> SQL adaption. Hint, you don't want to be passing in a list unless the db field `patrimonio` is an array type. Update your question to indicate what the field type is for `patrimonio`?

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution, I put it in an answer below this question, so all of you can use it for your projects. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the easiest solution like 2 minutes after I posted this question.

So when I made this code, I din't come up with a solution of storing a list of strings because it had an issue with the quotes inside the list and outside of it, but I after thought that I simply could use the list made with the `filter_info()` function and join it into a string.

Here's the old code:

```
cur.execute(f"""UPDATE "'{email}'"
                SET patrimonio = '''{patrimonio}'''
                WHERE "email" = '{email}';""")
```

And here's the new code:

```
cur.execute(f'''UPDATE "'{email}'"
                SET patrimonio = '{", ".join(patrimonio)}'
                WHERE "email" = '{email}';''')
```

I tried the new code a lot of times and it worked always like a charm, the only problem is that you wouldn't have a list in the database, but you can always `split()` the string into a list.

Comment: You still have a problem in that you are using `f` strings and not using parameter passing.